# How to get Dired to ignore files with specific extensions

Tags: emacs, dired

I put the following in my .emacs file:

```
(require 'dired-x)
(add-hook 'dired-load-hook '(lambda () (require 'dired-x)))
(setq dired-omit-files-p t)
(setq dired-omit-files
(concat dired-omit-files "\\|^\\..+$\\|-t\\.tex$\\|-t\\.pdf$"))
```

But `C-x d` still shows me .pdf and .tex files. Did I get the syntax wrong in that last line?

Bonus question: Is there a way to get Dired to hide hidden directories, like .git folders?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your regexp will match `*-t.tex` files, not `*.tex` ones.

With recent version of Emacs, it should be sufficient to add the following section to `~/.emacs` to filter what you want:

```
(require 'dired-x)
(setq-default dired-omit-files-p t) ; this is buffer-local variable
(setq dired-omit-files
    (concat dired-omit-files "\\|^\\..+$\\|\\.pdf$\\|\\.tex$"))
```

**Update:** by default, *dired-omit-files* regexp filters out special directories `.` and `..`. If you don't want this behavior, you can just override defaults (instead of inheriting them with *concat*):

```
(setq dired-omit-files "^\\.[^.]\\|\\.pdf$\\|\\.tex$")
```

The regexp `^\\.[^.]` will match any string of length 2+ starting with a dot where second character is any character except the dot itself. It's not perfect (will not match filenames like *"..foo"*), but should be ok most of the time.

Comment: Thanks! The above seems to also remove the `..` at the top of my Dired buffer that allows me to navigate up directory without needing to press `^`. Is there a way to restore the `..` navigation, but still hide folders like `.git`?

Comment: How could I also omit files that have following pattern: `flycheck_*.py` @barti_ddu

Comment: @alper: Just add another regular expression (via pipe) like `^flycheck_.*\\.py$`. And don't forget to escape the pipe, i.e. `\\|`.

Comment: My main goal is to accomplish it on `find-name-dired`, would it be also apply for that? I asked it  as follows: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/59245/how-to-ignore-files-starting-with-flycheck-on-find-name-dired @barti_ddu

Comment: @alper: IMHO, no. I would just use regular `find` in your case like `find-dired "~/dir" "-name \\*.py ! -name flycheck_\\*.py"`.

Answer (score 16):

A simple and very general solution which doesn't rely on any extras is to do `C-u s` to change the `ls` flags and immediately refresh (that is, `C-u s` takes care of refreshing also, so there is very little typing involved). Usually you will want to remove `-a` to hide dotfiles. But you can do everything you're already able to do in the shell console, which is far more than what a simple toggle mode could offer (at the cost of some extra keypressings). And there is a history of previous flags available, so "toggling" is pretty fast too.