# How to ignore .svn subdirectories when using dired

Tags: emacs, dired

I need to replace a string across many files in a directory tree.

So my plan is to use dired to first locate all the files that contain the string (with `% g`) and then replace the string with `Q`.

In order to show all subdirectories in the tree I use `C-u lR`. The problem is that this shows also the .svn directories, and I don't want to get inside them.

Is there a way of telling dired to ignore a given directory (or just hidden directories in general)?

I'm using Emacs 23.1.1.

Comment: PS Your version of Emacs is 5 years old!  You might consider updating to the newest version (24.4 will be out pretty soon).

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `.svn` extension to `dired-omit-files` with:

```
(setq dired-omit-files (concat dired-omit-files "\\|\\.svn$"))
```

See also [this related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14850103/how-do-i-get-emacs-dired-to-ignore-uninteresting-file-extensions) for more information.

Note, though, that you could just hide them (`dired-hide-dir`, bound to `$` and `dired-hide-all`, bound to `M-$`).  According to [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Hiding-Subdirectories.html#Hiding-Subdirectories):

> Ordinary Dired commands never consider files inside a hidden subdirectory. For example, the commands to operate on marked files ignore files in hidden directories even if they are marked. Thus you can use hiding to temporarily exclude subdirectories from operations without having to remove the Dired marks on files in those subdirectories.