# Hiding files in dired while using recursive flag

Tags: emacs, elisp, dired

My workspace tends to have a lot of .class clutter, and since I use the -R switch with dired to show my entire workspace for easier navigation, searching for something inevitably ends up matching a bunch of .class files that I have to go through before reaching the file I am looking for.

I used the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14850103/how-to-get-dired-to-ignore-files-with-specific-extensions), but found that it doesn't work with the recursive flag. When I navigate into a directory with .class files, it doesn't show them, as promised, but when I view the directory from somewhere above it, it still shows them.

Is there any way to properly hide/omit these files while using the recursive flag?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. (But I'm on MS Windows, which uses `ls-lisp.el`, which might make a difference here.)

*Please show more specifically what you do.*

1. I opened Dired on a directory, using `R` among the switches (e.g., `-alfR`), to get a recursive listing.
2. I turned on `dired-omit-mode` (the URL you posted shows the old way of using omission).

All of the expected files were omitted, throughout the buffer, i.e., from all included subdirs.

(Keep in mind that omission is buffer-specific, i.e., specific to each Dired buffer.)

Comment: I go to the directory ~/code using `C-x C-f`, which uses the switches `-lR`. Dired omit mode is turned on, and set to omit "\\|^\\..+$\\|\\.class$". When I go to ~/code, I see the contents of all subfolders, including a large number of class files in ~/code/project/.../component1/classes. When I navigate to ~/code/project/.../component1/classes, the class files cease to appear.

Comment: Sounds like a bug, maybe only for non-MS Windows platforms (which do not use `ls-lisp.el`, by default). Try loading `ls-lisp.el` and turning on ls-lisp emulation, to see if it makes a difference for you - see the Emacs manual, node [ls in Lisp](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/ls-in-Lisp.html). If that helps, consider reporting a bug: `M-x report-emacs-bug`. (And be sure that you do such testing starting from `emacs -Q`, to eliminate possible complications from your init file.)